# How can I condition ParameterGrid to match hyperparameters?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm tuning the number of layers and the number of nodes in each layer for a neural network, using `ParameterGrid` to get all combinations.

```
from itertools import combinations
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid

# Set hyperparameters
architecture_nodes = [8, 16, 32, 64, 128]
num_layers = [3,4]

architecture = []
for n in num_layers:
    architecture += list(combinations(architecture_nodes, n))

param_grid = {
             'num_layers': num_layers,
             'architecture': architecture
             }

grid = ParameterGrid(param_grid)
```

This method does what it is designed to, but that includes having a mismatch between the number of layers and number of nodes per layer.

```
print(list(grid)[:4])

[{'architecture': (8, 16, 32), 'num_layers': 3},
 {'architecture': (8, 16, 32), 'num_layers': 4},
 {'architecture': (8, 16, 64), 'num_layers': 3},
 {'architecture': (8, 16, 64), 'num_layers': 4},
 ]
```

I can use the line

```
list(filter(lambda hps: hps['num_layers'] == len(hps['architecture']), grid))
```

but is there a way I can directly filter the parameters in `ParameterGrid` to match? It seems like there would be a followup to this if I wanted to use a similar parameter grid in `GridSearchCV` as well.

Expected output is:

```
[{'architecture': (8, 16, 32), 'num_layers': 3},
 {'architecture': (8, 16, 64), 'num_layers': 3},
 {'architecture': (8, 16, 128), 'num_layers': 3},
 {'architecture': (8, 32, 64), 'num_layers': 3},
 {'architecture': (8, 32, 128), 'num_layers': 3},
 {'architecture': (8, 64, 128), 'num_layers': 3},
 {'architecture': (16, 32, 64), 'num_layers': 3},
 {'architecture': (16, 32, 128), 'num_layers': 3},
 {'architecture': (16, 64, 128), 'num_layers': 3},
 {'architecture': (32, 64, 128), 'num_layers': 3},
 {'architecture': (8, 16, 32, 64), 'num_layers': 4},
 {'architecture': (8, 16, 32, 128), 'num_layers': 4},
 {'architecture': (8, 16, 64, 128), 'num_layers': 4},
 {'architecture': (8, 32, 64, 128), 'num_layers': 4},
 {'architecture': (16, 32, 64, 128), 'num_layers': 4}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `param_grid` parameter as a *list* of dictionaries, and `ParameterGrid` will generate the disjoint union of the resulting grids.  So I think something like this should work:

```py
from itertools import combinations
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid

# Set hyperparameters
architecture_nodes = [8, 16, 32, 64, 128]
num_layers = [3,4]

param_grid = [
    {
        'num_layers': [n],
        'architecture': list(combinations(architecture_nodes, n)),
    }
    for n in num_layers
]

grid = ParameterGrid(param_grid)
```